# How solve an error of Hook in index.js file?

Tags: reactjs

I have an Hook's error in my index.js file. Normally the index.js file is still the default one. I don't know how to solve this error.

Here is the error :

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See [https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html][1] for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
./src/index.js
I:XXX/index.js:8

   5 | import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
   6 | import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
   7 | 
>  8 | ReactDOM.render(
   9 |   <BrowserRouter>
  10 |     <App />
  11 |   </BrowserRouter>,
```

Here is the index.js file :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: XXX
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I have exactly the same environment than my colleagues and it works for them. 
I already tried to restart my environment, start on another browser but the issue is still here.

Comment: This amount of logs doesn't help us to understand the issue. Probably your invalid hook call is in App component. So please share that

Comment: Can't see the error from here. need to go deeper into your code and show us where this hook is in the wrong place. or you've got a second react instance in your app.

Comment: I am working on the same project as op and it is working for most/all of us, so the issue definitely is not in the code but with react. Curiously this is only happening on one branch for them.

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided it seems like you are using react hooks in Class component which is not allowed. Hooks can be used only in functional component.

Check if `App` or `BrowserRouter` are class component and you are trying to use any of the hook calls in those class components.

Please follow the [link](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) for further info.

If you would share more code it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I am working on the same project and it is working for most of us, so the issue definitely is not in the code but with react. Curiously this is only happening on one branch for them.

Comment: For that falsy branch, you guys can check the version of react and react DOM in `Package.json` file to confirm if it's as per directives in the link shared by me.
  Moreover, if possible, you guys can share the link of the branch here so that community will help better. 

Thanks